# Passing Json response Data to another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my application, I am trying to get the list of peoples from the database and displaying it on the html elements. There are more than one people. for every people, I am showing there name and two `<h4>` that works as button 'Emailme and Textme' for me. So say for example, if I click on People1's Emailme button, it should send the email to p1@test.com and if I click on People2's Emailme button, it should send the email to p2@test.com. For getting these people's email id I am using '.data' attribute to set the values to the element itself. I am getting the email for that people of whom I have clicked the button. But I don't know how to pass that value to actaully make it work.

here is my code:

In **Index.php**

```
<div id="peoples" class="peoples_results_list" style="display: none;">
    <div class="result" id="result_list">
        <h4>Peoples</h4>
        <div id="people_info" class="people_information">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="name" class="people_name">
                    <h5></h5>
                    <p></p>
                </div>             
            </div>                 
        </div>
        <div id="email_btn" class="contact_btn">
            <h4 id="emailme"></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ContactForm" class='form_overlay' style="display: none;">
    <h2>Email us</h2>
    <form action="#">
        <input class='vk' id="pname" placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
        <input class='vk' id="psubject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" required />
        <input class='vk' id="pemail" placeholder="Email" type="text" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required />
        <textarea class='vk' id="pmessage" placeholder="Write your Message here..." required></textarea>
        <i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:36px"></i>
        <button type="button" class='button' onclick="submitEmailForm()">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</div>


<script>
$('#logo').on("click",function(){
    var $list = $('#peoples');

    $.post('/go/getInfo', {}, function(data){
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
            var $template = $('#result_list').clone();
            $template.find('#name h5').html('Name');
            $template.find('#name p').html(data[i]['name']);

            var email_btn = $template.find('#email_btn h4');
            email_btn.data('email',data[i]['email']);

            $template.find('#email_btn h4').html("Email Me");
            $("#email_btn h4").click(function(){
                $('#ContactForm').fadeIn();
            });

            $template.show();
            $('#peoples').show();

            $list.append($template);        
        }  
    });
});


function submitEmailForm(){        
    var name = $('#pname').val();
    var email = $('#pemail').val();
    var subject = $('#psubject').val();
    var message = $('#pmessage').val();


    if(name == "" || email == "" || message == "" || subject == ""){
        alert("All fields are Required");
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/go/sendEmail',
            data: {
                name: name,
                subject: subject,
                email: email,
                message: message,
            },
            success: function(msg){

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In **go.php**

```
<?php

public function sendEmail(){
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $email = new \Email\Default();
        $mergeTags = [
            'CONTENT'=>$message." from - ". $name
        ];
        $this->toJson($email->setTo(['email' => $to, 'name' => $name, 'type' => 'to'])->setSubject($subject)->setTemplate('default')->setMergeTags($mergeTags)->send());
    }
}

?>
```

AS shown is above and as below code, I have set the value of email of that particular to the element itself and want to pass that value to the backend to actually send the email to that people only.

```
var email_btn = $template.find('#email_btn h4');
email_btn.data('email',data[i]['email']);
```

I tried adding something like below in my `function submitEmailForm()`:

```
var toEmail = $('#email_btn').data('email');
```

and in '.post'

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/go/sendEmail',
            data: {
                name: name,
                subject: subject,
                email: email,
                message: message,
                to_emp_email: toEmail
            }
```

But obviosuly doen't work. Any idea how can I achieve that ? help is appreciated.

**Edited**

Tried the below code, it sends the mail but to the last People's email. For example if there are 3 People(p1,p2,p3) in the list, doesn't matter to whom I am sending, it always sending to the 3rd Person(p3's) email.

In **Index.php** in function `submitEmailForm()`

```
var toEmail = email_btn.data('email');

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/go/sendEmail',
            data: {
                name: name,
                subject: subject,
                email: email,
                message: message,
                to_emp_email: toEmail
            }
```

In **go.php** in function sendEmail()

```
$toEmail = $_POST['to_emp_email'];
```

This is working but all the time storing the last person's email and sending to that email only.

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(toEmail);` ?

Comment: And is this a typo `$('email_btn')` ? it should be `$('#email_btn')` !

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I am getting 'undefined' for that and yes it was typo in here. I corrected in question. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: And what's the console result ?

Comment: for `console.log(toEmail);` I am getting undefined. 
and I tried `var_dump($_POST['to_emp_email'])` in my go.php-> `function sendEmail()` and I am getting an error of "Undefined Index: to_emp_email "'

Comment: When you inspect the elements , do you see  an attribute  `data-email` in  your email_btn ?

Comment: No, I can't see data-email in my email_btn.
But when I do `$($0).data('email')` in console window while inspecting, I am getting the correct value for each of the people's email. So now I want to pass the value of `var email_btn` to my another function that calls backend function `sendEmail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Samantha,

When you do `$('#result_list').clone();`, you duplicate the `#result_list` an all it's content! In this case, you'll have so many elements with the same `ID`. And that's worng because an `ID` must be [unique](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). That's why you are getting the last `email` only.

I would suggest to test this :

```
$.post('/go/getInfo', {}, function(data){
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ){
        var $template = $('#result_list').clone();
        $template.find('#name').attr("id", "name"+i); //A unique ID for Name
        $('#name'+i).find('h5').html('Name');
        $('#name'+i).find('p').html(data[i]['name']);

        $template.find('#email_btn').attr("id", "email_btn"+i); //A unique ID for button
        var email_btn = $('email_btn'+i).find('h4');
        email_btn.data('email',data[i]['email']);

        email_btn.html("Email Me");
        email_btn.click(function(){
            //Assign the email of the "Email Me" button, to the send Email Button                
            $('#ContactForm').find('button').data('email',$(this).data('email'));
            $('#ContactForm').fadeIn();
        });

        $template.show();
        $('#peoples').show();

        $list.append($template);        
    }  
});
```

Then, in your `submitEmailForm()`, you can get the current email :

```
var sendEmailButton = $('#ContactForm').find('button');
var toEmail = sendEmailButton.data('email');
//And here your AJAX
```

I hope this helps!